# Convergence of linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

I want to determine wether the functional $\varphi_n:\ell^2\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$\varphi_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt k x_k\quad x=(x_1,x_2,\dots)$$ converges in norm, or in weak sense.

The norm of the functional is bounded, by C.S inequality: $$|\varphi_n|\le\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n k}\cdot \Vert{x}\Vert=\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{2n}}\cdot\Vert x\Vert\Rightarrow \Vert\varphi_n\Vert\le\frac{1}{2}.$$ Also taking the dense set of the finitely supported sequences $\{(1,0,0,\dots),(1,1,0,0,\dots)\}$, $$\varphi_n(x)=\frac 1 n(1+\sqrt 2+\dots \sqrt m)\to 0\quad x=(\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_m,0,\dots).$$ Hence the functional converges to $0$ in weak sense.

**EDIT:** On the other hand, using methods from Minkowski inequality proof: $$\Vert \varphi_n\Vert=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2}}\to\sqrt{\frac 1 2}.$$ which proves the convergence is not in norm.

This proof is legit?

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct. Only the bound $\Vert \varphi_n \Vert \leq 1/2$ is a bit off.

Comment: The norm of the functional is 1 for n=1.And less than 1 for n greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by  PhoemueX, the proof is correct. However, we do not have $\lVert \varphi_n\rVert\leqslant 1/2$. For example, if we take $x$ such that $x_k=\sqrt k$ for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$ and $x_k=0$ for the other $k$'s, then 
$$\frac{\left|\varphi_n(x)\right|}{\lVert x\rVert}=\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot \frac 1{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n k}}=\frac 1n\sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}},$$
which is greater than $1/2$. 
However, the computations in the opening post showed that 
$$\lVert \varphi_n\rVert\leqslant \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{2n}}$$
which is bounded independently on $n$ (for example by $1$), since $n+1\leqslant 2n$.